# AWS Lambda Function will Not Deserialize Payload

Tags: java, aws-lambda, deserialization

So, I'm pretty well versed with AWS lambda, but I am baffled as to why this will not work for me.

I have a class set up:

```
public class ClassToDeserialize {
    private String token;
    private String bucketName;
    private String fileFormat;
    private int index;

    public ClassToDeserialize(String token, String bucketName, String fileFormat, int index) {
        this.token = token;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.fileFormat = fileFormat;
        this.index = index;
    }

    //PLUS ALL THE GETS AND SETS
}
```

Then in my lambda Handler:

```
    public String handleRequest(ClassToDeserialize payload, Context context) {

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(payload));
        return "done";
}
```

The input sent to this lambda is this:

```
{
  "token": "IAMATOKEN",
  "bucketName": "this-is-my-bucket",
  "fileFormat": "text",
  "index": 0
}
```

But the System.out statement prints this:

```
{
    "token": null,
    "bucketName": null,
    "fileFormat": null,
    "index": 0
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this might be happening? I am seriously confused because I have used lambda for quite a while and I always used it this way successfully.. I just don't know what could be breaking down now.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is correct, you need to check what is happening before and why object with null values are reaching that method.

If you for example do in `handleRequest(ClassToDeserialize payload)` the following

`payload = new ClassToDeserialize("a","b","c",1)` and then call `gson.toJson(payload)` it will show you that all above code is correct and you need to dig deeper.